# Fetch only number from name number pair

Tags: android, android-contacts, string-parsing

We have contacts displayed as `Name <123-456-767>`

I want to fetch only the number part `123456767` if the specified address is a valid one.

Can anyone can help me !!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Whats your criteria for a valid address?  Are you looking at using regular expressions here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public static String stripSeparators (String phoneNumber)`

Since: API Level 1
Strips separators from a phone number string.
Parameters phoneNumber phone number to strip

`Returns phone string stripped of separators.`

Answer (score 2):

Or, even simpler:

`"Name <123-456-767>".replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");`

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions:

```
private static final Pattern NUMBER_PART = Pattern.compile(".+ <([0-9\\-]+)>");

...

Matcher matcher = NUMBER_PART.matcher(contact);
if (matcher.find()) {
    String number_part = matcher.group(1);
    number_part = number_part.replace("-", "");
}
```